# How can I add an end-user-friendly "Add Relation" block?

Tags: entities

*Note: I am currently using Entity Reference, but am willing to use a different module if it makes the solution easier.*

I am currently developing a recipe-sharing site with two content types - "Recipes" and "Recipe books". The idea is that each user can create their own Recipe Book(s), and can add recipes to them. There are two problems with the out-of-the-box solution:

1. Most of these users are not tech-savvy, and there are a large number of them, so asking them to search an autocomplete "Entity Reference" form inside of the Recipe Books content type isn't the best bet.
2. Since many recipes will be added to each book, it would make more sense to have an "Add to Book" feature on each recipe display page (think Amazon's "Add to Wishlist" feature - then lets you choose which wishlist the object is added to).

I've already tried the Relation module with the Entity Collector block, but even though it's functionally similar to what I wanted, I couldn't quite get it working on the site and it's not at all user-friendly. I'm hoping for a simpler solution that doesn't involve a lot of custom coding, and still allows all users to interact with the content type as needed.

Thanks in advance for help / suggestions!